# modify existing registry key innoSetup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

During my installation with InnoSetup I want to change an existing key of wampapache service created by the software Wamp

The Code:

**[Registry]**

**Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\wampapache" ValueType: dword; ValueName: "Start" ValueData: "2"**

The ValueData 2 allows the service to start automatically at boot.
 My problem is the Subkey 'SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ services \ wampapache "
contains several rows and when I launch my installation all the rows disappear except the the one I just created "Start" with the value 3.
How to update the key without deleting other existing rows?

Comment: Is that your **exact** code for `[Registry]`? Did you copy and paste it there? There spaces between the subkeys and \ ? And did you forget a `;` between `"Start"` and `ValueData`?

Comment: No it's not the exact code, there is no ecepace between the \ and there is an enter after [registry] here the doc link: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php ? topic = runsection
I do not have the syntax error,the compiler don't generates errors

Comment: Please edit your question to include the EXACT code in your entire `[Registry]` section.  Remember to put four spaces at the start of each line to preserve it as a code snippet.

Comment: sorry, I don't know why when I test the code again it worked, the code is correct there are no errors, thank you for all